# How to get Events of Facebook Funpage via Open Graph - when I am NOT logged in? Is it possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-events

Im wondering if it is possible to get EVENTS of some facebook page via OPEN GRAPH when user is not logged in. I don't want to create facebook APP. I would like to have just some http link let say

.... page/ID/events which will get me JSON events code.

I know that it is possible to get it via access_token but I don't want to use it.
I just want to get PUBLIC EVENTS.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

Try this url: [South Park Page](https://graph.facebook.com/southpark), you should see the data even though there's no access token.
Now, try this url: [South Park Page Events](https://graph.facebook.com/southpark/events), you should get an error for not having an access token.
But, if you try it with an access token (for example with the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)): [South Park Page Events](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=southpark/events) you should get the data.

You can also check the documentation for the [Page object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), where it says that for the *events* connection you need:

> any valid access_token or user access_token

There aren't many things that you can do with out an access token. But you can sometimes use an App Token and not a user one. Still requires you to have a fb app though.

Comment: Well, it only makes sense. Facebook need to know who's making the request in order to know what they can response back. If this answers what you wanted to know, please accept the answer. Thanks.